# Flex AdvancedDataGridColumn dataTipFunction query

Tags: apache-flex

I've a AdvancedDataGridColumn which has both 'labelFunction' and 'dataTipFunction' defined.

I want dataTipFunction to return the output of 'labelFunction' + someText.

Could anyone please help in this regard?

P.S : The problem here is dataTipFunction doesn't have access to 'column' object.

Thanks.

Comment: Just want to know if a single dataTipFunction serves the purpose or I'll have to write one dataTipFunction for each column. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the labelFunction on the datagridcolumn in your dataTipFunction and append something to the result.

```
var label:String = column.labelFunction(item, column);
return label + someText;
```

I would however suggest to extract the code that creates the label into its own method and then call this method in both the labelFunction and the dataTipFunction. Since this information is missing, you cannot do this dynamically.

---

PS: Since the dataTipFunction does not include the column property, you'll need to create a datatip function for each column and add the column information. You can then invoke the labelFunction on the correct column.

```
private function dataTipFunction1(item:Object):String {
  return getDataTip(item, myFirstColumn);
}

private function dataTipFunction2(item:Object):String {
  return getDataTip(item, mySecondColumn);
}

private function getDataTip(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String {
  return column.labelFunction(item, column) + someText;
}
```

Comment: dataTipFunction has access to only item but not column.

Comment: Indeed, I added some extra info.